# Recursively create accordion html from list of links in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, html-lists, html-agility-pack

I am scraping a remote page for links, which I have in a List.  I am trying to get the list printed out as necessary for a jquery accordion.  I have the html no problem, but my loops are off a bit and aren't nesting properly.

Here is an example of the List:

```
<a href="#heading1">Heading 1</a>
<a href="link1.html">link1</a>
<a href="link2.html">link2</a>
<a href="link3.html">link3</a>
<a href="#heading2">Heading 2</a>
<a href="link4.html">link4</a>
<a href="link5.html">link5</a>
<a href="link6.html">link6</a>
```

So here is how I need to get the html formatted:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Heading 1</h3>
<p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link1.html">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.html">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html">link3</a></li>
  </ul>
</p>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Heading 2</h3>
<p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link4.html">link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="link5.html">link5</a></li>
    <li><a href="link6.html">link6</a></li>
  </ul>
</p>
</div>
```

And here is the code I have so far, it should be mentioned I am using the HTMLAgilityPack:

```
HtmlNodeCollection OneHome = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='accordion1']");
        var OneHomelinks = OneHome.Descendants("a")
                .Select(a => a.OuterHtml)
                .ToList();

        foreach (string link in OneHomelinks)
        {

            if (link.Contains('#'))
            {
                Response.Write("<div data-role=\"collapsible\" data-collapsed=\"true\">");
                Response.Write("<h3>" + link + "</h3>");
                Response.Write("<p>");
                Response.Write("<ul>");
            }

            if (!link.Contains('#'))
            {
                Response.Write("<li>" + link + "</li>");
            } else {
                Response.Write("</ul>");
                Response.Write("</p>");
                Response.Write("</div>");
            }

        }
```

Basically I am trying to pull out the Headings by using the '#' in the href, and resetting the  at that point - but something is off, the lists aren't being properly formed.  Any help is super appreciated here!

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Heading 1</h3>
<p></p>
 <ul></ul>
<p></p>
</div>
<li><a href="link1.html>link1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2.html>link2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3.html>link3</a></li>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Heading 2</h3>
<p></p>
 <ul></ul>
<p></p>
</div>
<li><a href="link4.html>link4</a></li>
<li><a href="link5.html>link5</a></li>
<li><a href="link6.html>link6</a></li>
```

Comment: what's your current output

Comment: _sidenote_ your art = :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Logic in the wrong spot, whoops!

**Edit 2:** Once more with logic placement.

I think this should work for you:

```
HtmlNodeCollection OneHome = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='accordion1']");
    var OneHomelinks = OneHome.Descendants("a")
            .Select(a => a.OuterHtml)
            .ToList();
    var headerCount = 0;
    foreach (string link in OneHomelinks)
    {
        var prevCounter = headerCount;
        if (link.Contains('#'))
        {
            headerCount++;

            if (headerCount != 1 && headerCount > prevCounter) {
                Response.Write("</ul>");
                Response.Write("</p>");
                Response.Write("</div>");
            }

            Response.Write("<div data-role=\"collapsible\" data-collapsed=\"true\">");
            Response.Write("<h3>" + link + "</h3>");
            Response.Write("<p>");
            Response.Write("<ul>");


        }
        else {
            Response.Write("<li>" + link + "</li>");
        } 
    }
    Response.Write("</ul>");
    Response.Write("</p>");
    Response.Write("</div>");
```

Comment: Closer - Now its wrapping everything a single <ul> and nesting everything deeper x1 level each time it finds a Heading.

Comment: I see my logic placement was duplicated instead of moved, I've updated the code for real this time. :)

Comment: Still nesting everything within the first <ul> here is a screenshot: http://d.pr/i/gC7N

Comment: Ah, yeah I think I see why. Updated once more.